# Listen on different ports with one spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Is it possible to listen on different ports using spring cloud gateway?
For example:

1. Forward requests from port 80 to localhost:8080
2. Forward requests from port 81 to localhost:8081